# powershell indexof is not working

Tags: powershell

can you please help to resolve the problem with string.indexof.
here is what I do:
1. save below into log1.txt with ANSI.

```
   192.168.17.54,207.68.172.246 7:49am
   292.168.17.54,207.68.172.246 7:41am
   392.168.17.54,207.68.172.246 7:42am
```

2. run code:

> $b=get-content -Path log1.txt -Encoding ascii

## -- string '192' is not found within $b and $b shows all values from the file.

3. > $b.IndexOf('192')-1

   When I do not use get-content -

   > $b.indexof finds '192'

   What am I missing here?

Comment: You save it as single line or as multiple lines?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns an array of strings, and arrays have their own `.IndexOf()` method which looks for items in the array. `"192"` is not a complete string in the array, so it's not found.

You want either `Get-Content -Raw` to return a single string, or more likely `Get-Content ... | ForEach-Object { $_.IndexOf("192") }` to test each line one at a time.

Or something like `select-string` to test any line in the file.

Comment: Than you TessellatingHeckler, -raw option has worked exactly as I wanted.